# Android Cast SDK V3 and MediaRouteProviderService

Tags: android, chromecast, mediarouteproviderservice

I was using cast SDK v2  to cast media on routes provided `MediaRouteProviderService` which was working great.

Now I am migrating to [SDK v3](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_migrate_sender) and its states

> In v3, the discovery process is started and stopped automatically by
>   the framework when the app comes to the foreground and goes to the
>   background, respectively. MediaRouteSelector and MediaRouter.Callback
>   should not be used

So how to provide custom routes using `MediaRouteProviderService` with cast SDK v3

Answer (score 0):

**So how to provide custom routes using MediaRouteProviderService with cast SDK v3**

In v3, device discovery is now being handled by CastContext. In [v3 Configure device discovery](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate), it states that:

> Device discovery is completely managed by the
>   [CastContext](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext).
>   When initializing the CastContext, the sender app specifies the
>   receiver application ID, and can optionally request namespace
>   filtering by setting supportedNamespaces in
>   [CastOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastOptions).
>   CastContext holds a reference to the MediaRouter internally, and will
>   start the discovery process when the sender app enters the foreground,
>   and stop when the sender app enters background.

```
class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
    public static final String CUSTOM_NAMESPACE = "urn:x-cast:custom_namespace";
    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {
        List<String> supportedNamespaces = new ArrayList<>();
        supportedNamespaces.add(CUSTOM_NAMESPACE);
        CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
            .setSupportedNamespaces(supportedNamespaces)
            .build();
        return castOptions;
    }
    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This means MediaRouteProviderService is no longer needed, instead provide custom routes using OptionsProvider, am I correct?